# OCR example, class cannot resolve

Tags: android, class, manifest, ocr

i try to learn OCR example with this (http://www.codepool.biz/making-an-android-ocr-application-with-tesseract.html) but have a problem on manifest:

```
"android:name="com.dynamsoft.tessocr.OCRActivity"
```

I have problem with OCRActivity, cannot resolve symbol "**OCRActivity**"

But i have the class

[image: one]

Y try a lot, but cant use any OCR example

Comment: clean project and rebuild?

Comment: I have downloaded several times

Comment: simebody can help me?